# Why is acceleration $\frac{1}{2}at^2$ halved when finding final height (distance)?

Tags: calculus, limits, physics, mathematical-physics

The final distance of an object dropped from a certain height is:

$$S_f=S_0-\frac{1}{2}at^2,$$

$S_f=$ Final distance
$S_0=$ Initial height from which the object was dropped
$a=$ acceleration due to gravity (gravitational acceleration)
$t=$ the time traveled by object.

1. Why is $a$ halved? It goes from $9.8$ to $4.9$.
2. Why is the time $t$ squared?

These are basic equations, however, I couldn't find **explanations** as to the *whys*, only methodology telling me to "plug in".
Thank you.

Comment: The derivative of the distance is the speed and only with the formula as above we doobtain $v(t) = -at$, that is the speed changes linearly and the rate of change is precisely $-a$. The acceleration is "the change of speed" hence this is just what we want for constant acceleration.

Comment: The acceleration doesn't change, the $1/2$ comes from the area of a trapezoid, someone in a while will explain it better.

Comment: In the beginning the speed of the object is $0$. After time $t$ the speed of the object is $at$. Since speed increases uniformly, the average speed over this time interval is $(0+at)/2=\frac12at$, so...

Comment: @Rahul: Yours is the only reply that answers the OP's question!

Comment: @RahulNarain Thanks, I would accept that as an answer if you post it in the answer section :)

Answer (score 4):

Acceleration is the second time derivative of position. If it's constant, we have:
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} x = a_0$$
Integrate both sides:
$$\frac{d}{dt} x = a_0 t + v_0$$
If we integrate both sides again, we get:
$$x = \frac{1}{2} a_0 t^2 + v_0 t + x_0$$

The $v_0$ and $x_0$ come from the constants of integration, and are given by the initial conditions.

Another reason there's a one half: after time $t$ has passed, the velocity is $a_0 t + v_0$. But it hasn't been going that speed the entire time, it started at $v_0$. So the position must be less than $v(t) t + x_0 = a_0 t^2 + v_0 t + x_0$. That the coefficient is exactly one half should be shown more rigorously, but at least we know it's less than one.

Answer (score 1):

**About the halving:**

When the speed is constant, $s=vt$ is obvious.

When you accelerate or decelerate between $0$ and $v$, it is also obvious that $s<vt$. And more precisely, if the growth or decay is linear, you get exactly the half (intuitively because you are as much "slow" as you are "fast").

**About the squaring:**

The speed is $\propto t$, hence by the above reasoning, $s\propto vt\propto t^2$.

Answer (score 0):

We consider an object of mass $m$ dropped.

Newton's second law: $F=ma$.

Newton's law of gravitation: $F = G\displaystyle\frac{mM}{r^2}$

Equating the forces gives $a=\displaystyle\frac{GM}{r^2}$

As an aside, this proves that gravitational acceleration is independent of the mass of the object (since $G$ is constant and $M$ is the mass of the earth, also constant), reminiscent of the famous Pisa experiment.

We also note that gravitational acceleration in this context is [approximated by] a constant $-a$, so solving the IVP $$\begin{cases}x''=-a\\ x'(0)=0\\ x(0)=S_0\end{cases}$$ gives $x(t)=S_0-\displaystyle\frac a2 t^2$. The halving is just a mathematical consequence of the differential equations, so is the time's square.

Answer (score 0):

In basic scenarios, we multiply an object's velocity $(v)$ by the time it traveled $(t)$ to obtain its distance traveled $(d)$.

$d=vt$

However, when the velocity is changing, we can't use the formula as it is. We first need to find a single velocity value that is representative of the object's velocity over the whole time interval. In other words, we need the object's *average velocity*, which we can then multiply by time.

$d=v_{average}\cdot t$

Generally, we would first have to integrate the velocity function, then divide that value by the time traveled in order to obtain average velocity. In this case however, gravity causes the velocity to change at a *constant rate* $(a)$, so the velocity is modeled by a *linear function*. This makes it very convenient for us to figure out the average velocity. All we need to do is add the initial velocity and final velocity, then divide by 2.

$v_{average}=\frac{v_{initial}+v_{final}}{2}$

We also know that we obtain $v_{final}$ by taking $v_{initial}$ and subtracting the change in velocity that occurs due to gravity.

$v_{final}=v_{initial}-at$

We can substitute this expanded version of $v_{final}$ into the average velocity equation and simplify.

$\begin{align}
v_{average}=\frac{v_{initial}+v_{initial}-at}{2}\\
=v_{initial}-\frac{1}{2}at
\end{align}$

Now that we have the average velocity expression, we can plug it into the basic distance formula from before.

$d=(v_{initial}-\frac{1}{2}at)\cdot t$

By distributing $t$, we get:

$d=v_{initial}\cdot t-\frac{1}{2}at^2$